# How to parallelize a loop in OpenACC with a "min" fuction inside

Tags: c++, min, openacc

I would like to parallel this loop with the ***"min"*** fuction in OpenACC but it has not been possible. The compiler shows the following message after compilation:

**The 121 line belongs to the for(k=j+1;k<=bi;k++)**

PGCC-S-0155-Invalid accelerator region: branching into or out of region is not allowed  (LATSONEopenacc.cpp: 121)
main:
      121, Invalid accelerator region: branching into or out of region is not allowed
const T1 & std::min(const T1 &, const T1 &):
      1, include "iostream"
          39, include "ostream"
               38, include "ios"
                    40, include "char_traits.h"
                         39, include "stl_algobase.h"
                             194, Generating implicit acc routine seq
                                  Generating acc routine seq
                                  Generating Tesla code
PGCC/x86 Linux 17.10-0: compilation completed with severe errors

```
//code in c++
#pragma acc parallel loop reduction(min:mini)  
for(k=j+1;k<=bi;k++){

resultt=( ((auxx[i][k]-auxx[i][j])*(auxx[i][k]-auxx[i][j]))+((auxy[i][k]-auxy[i][j])*(auxy[i][k]-auxy[i][j])));

      mini=std::min(resultt,mini);

}
```

For compilation, I am using the command :

```
pgc++ -acc -ta=nvidia,time -Minfo=accel LATSONEopenacc.cpp -o output
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"std::min" contains an exception handler, hence the message about branching outside of the parallel regions.  To work around this issue, add the flag "--no_exceptions" to disable exception handling.